# How do I remove commas only from inside double quotes for every line in a comma delimited csv?

Tags: csv, awk, sed

I have a comma delimited CSV file that encapsulates the fields in double quote that I am attempting to operate on in bash. I would like to remove commas from inside the double quoted field for each line. I've looked at other solutions for the question asked here, and they revolved around using external libraries for CSV parsing, which isn't an option for my limited environment where the majority of the work is being done in awk and sed.

```
"A","B","C D","E, F","G"
```

desired output

```
"A","B","C D","E F","G"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With sed, to remove all commas followed by one non quote character and commas not preceded by one non quote character:

```
sed 's/,*\([^"]\)/\1/g;s/\([^"]\),*/\1/g' file
```

**Edit:**

Added `*` quantifier to match subsequent commas.

Answer (score 1):

Easy with Perl's [Text::CSV_XS](http://p3rl.org/Text::CSV_XS) module:

```
perl -MText::CSV_XS=csv -we 'csv(
    in           => shift,
    always_quote => 1,
    on_in        => sub { tr/,//d for @{ $_[1] } }
);' -- file.csv
```

- `in` specifies the input, [shift](http://p3rl.org/shift) just takes one from the command line arguments
- `always_quote` adds quotes even to fields that don't need them
- `on_in` introduces code to run on each line, in this case, it iterates over all the cells in the row and removes commas using the transliteration operator `tr`.

Answer (score 0):

With GNU awk and [`FPAT`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Splitting-By-Content.html):

```
$ awk '
BEGIN {
    FPAT = "([^,]+)|(\"[^\"]+\")"  # field definition
    OFS=","                        # output field separator
}
{
    for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)             # loop all fields
        gsub(/,/,"",$i)}           # replace all commas in fields
1' file                            # output
"A","B","C D","E F","G"
```

Answer (score 0):

I like ruby for CSV one-liners:

```
ruby -rcsv -ne '
  CSV.parse($_) {|row|
    puts row.map {|field| field.delete(",")}
            .to_csv(:force_quotes => true)
  }
'
```